# How do I use compressed textures on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, pvrtc

Are there any tutorials that can teach me how to use mipmapping in my program? I already know how to generate mipmaps, but i want to find out how to read, load and use the pvr file in my program.

Comment: This isn't really about mipmaps; it's about compressed textures-- I've edited the tags & title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple details how to use PVRTC texture compression [in their documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html).

It covers using their "texturetool" to compress textures (which includes automatic mipmap chain generation), and then in code how to upload the textures.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has very straight forward [example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html) showing how to read PVR textures (including its mipmap chain).